# How can I use an additionaly temporaly math font to declare a macro using libertinusT1math

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, math-fonts, libertine, libertinus

I would like to style my book more, until now I'm using `\mathbfit` for vectors\matrices. I would like to use another italic bold math font to type the same characters, e.g. `x` and `y` to denote different math objects. Is there an elegant or easy way?

My goal is to declare a macro for that, along the line `\newcommand{\matrixalt}[1]{\setanothermathfont\mathbfit#1}`

I'm using this setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[ISO, upint]{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,bb=boondox]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final,babel=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \mathbfit{y}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the other font you want to use?

Comment: Is there a tool where I can compare different fonts side by side? I still need to decide on the font. Since both symbols would be typed closed, I need the second font to be visually different from the first, e.g. also a little taller if possible. I'm thinking about typing 'x' and 'y' in italic and bold styles